# Can I change a sub-directory icon from the root of a removable drive?

Tags: windows, icons, desktop.ini

I'm currently in the process of making themes for my removable disks for my PC. I'm using individual icon format images located at the root of each folder that has a custom icon using a `Desktop.ini` file in tandem with the correlating icon. For each of the custom folders, I have placed this in the `.ini` file to draw the icon resource:

```
[.ShellClassInfo]
IconFile=%ICONNAME%.ico
IconIndex=0
InfoTip=
```

What I would like to do is use a single `.res` file at the root of the drive that contains all of the theme icons and does the same thing. I also want to do this so I can avoid using an icon group for each folder, in that folder, I want to singularize them into the `.res` file. However, I want to avoid using static or fixed drive letters to do this. Is there a way to have a sub-directory on the drive draw from the resource file while allowing the icons to appear regardless of which port the disk is in? What would I put in the `.ini` to "backtrack" the resource from the drive root?

Comment: You can change folder icon by right click and select change icon. Write the 2nd line as `IconResource=D:\Abc.ico,0`. See this article:: https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/13631/customize-your-icons-in-windows-7-and-vista/

Comment: While that method *does* work, I am trying to remove the drive letter from the equation. Otherwise, I would need to insert the drive in the corrisponding port each time for the icon to appear.

Comment: Then use a system environment variable like `%SystemRoot%` for C:\Windows. Or put that icon file and desktop.ini both in that folder of which icon you want to change.